# Does an integrable function have to have a point of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

I wanted to ask the following question:
If f is Riemann integrable in [a, b], is there necessarily a point in [a, b] where f is continuous?
I know there is a theorem that states that f is integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities is measure 0. Does that imply that in a closed interval, f must have a point of continuity? Or is this not necessarily true?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the set of discontinuities has measure $0$, then it cannot coincide with the whole interval, because the interval has strictly positive measure. Do you agree? Therefore, the set of discontinuities must be strictly contained in the interval, and so, there must be at least a point of continuity. (Actually, there's much more than just one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interval has Lebesgue measure equal to its length, so an entire genuine interval (not $(a,a) $ or $[a,a] $) cannot be contained in the set of discontinuities of a Riemann-integrable function.